# how to trigger on-screen keyboard appearance on web page?

Tags: html, touchscreen

We built a web application that is used in full screen (kiosk) mode. It works fine with keyboard and mouse. We now have few PCs with windows 8 and touch screens (HP smart touch). 
How can we force keyboard appearance when user touch any input field?
I have noticed it work like this for some websites.